# Highstocks add n number of series to chart in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts

I have a model called 'hack' that can have many 'serials'.  Each 'serial' can have many 'observations'.  'observations' is where the chart data (e.g. date and value reside).  I want to be able to create a chart of a single hack that can have a variable number of serials, each of which contain the values for the chart within 'observations.

My hack controller's 'show' action looks like this:

```
def show
  @hack = Hack.find(params[:id])
  @obj = {}
  @hack.serials.each do |s|
    @obj[:name] = s.series_name
    data = s.observations.order("id asc").map{|x| [x.hs_date, x.value]}.to_s.gsub('"', '')
    @obj[:data] = data
  end
end
```

The show.html.erb file looks like this:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
  // Create the chart
  window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart : {
      renderTo : 'container'
    },
    series : 
      <%= raw @obj.to_json %>
    });
});
</script>
```

When running this code the chart displays 'invalid date'.  I know the data is correct because Highstocks correctly generates the chart when I'm using a single data series.  In that case the hack controller's show action is:

```
def show
  @hack = Hack.find(params[:id])
end
```

With the show.html.erb file as:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
  // Create the chart
  window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart : {
      renderTo : 'container'
    },
    series : [{
      name: 'first',
      data: <%= raw @serial.observations.order("id asc").map{|x| [x.hs_date, x.value]}.to_s.gsub('"', '') %>
            }]
   });
 });
 </script>
```

My question is how to add n number of serials, with n = the number of serials in a particular hack to a Highstocks chart from rails?

Comment: The whole serials, hacks, etc. was slightly hard to follow, but does one "Serial" equate to one "line" in the graph?

Comment: @MatthewKremer, yes. A serial can be something like "US GDP" where the observations are the actual values of GDP for a given date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so if I understand this correctly, you want each Serial to show up as its own line in one graph. I don't know Ruby on Rails, so I'm going to "comment" code here.

The basic concept is that each serial should be it's own series {} in the series list.

```
def show
  @hack = Hack.find(params[:id])
  @objs = []
  @hack.serials.each do |s|
    @obj = {}
    @obj[:name] = s.series_name
    data = s.observations.order("id asc").map{|x| [x.hs_date, x.value]}.to_s.gsub('"', '')
    @obj[:data] = data
    @objs APPEND THE NEW @obj
  end
end
```

Then use `to_json` inside of an `eval` with the new `@objs` array:

```
var d = eval('<%= raw @objs.to_json %>');
```

After we're done with that you must look through the string arrays to turn them into javascript arrays, then you can pass "d" as the value for series.

```
for (var i=0;i<d.length;i++){
   d[i]['data'] = eval(d[i]['data']);   
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mkremer90/mNxxF/5/) showing the concept.

Comment: I want each hack to be able to process multiple series in the same chart.  So if a hack1 has three series it will produce a chart comparing the three series, and if hack2 has two series it will produce a chart comparing those two series, etc.

Comment: Correct, sorry if I worded my first sentence wrong, this solution should work for you. Could you try it and let me know? You want each serial to be a {} with name and data inside of a list. So you'll wind up with [{name: 'Test', data: stuff},{name: 'Test 2', data: stuff}].

Comment: I still get the invalid date from Highstocks.  Here is partially what is rendered via view source: series : 
        [{"name":"AFEXPND","data":"[[-1293840000000, 2.6], [-1262304000000, 2.7], [-1230768000000, 4.0],  Highstocks unfortunately doesn't like it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that negative numbers will not work as dates, try converting them to positives before sending the data.

Comment: Negative numbers work they are just dates before 1970 (epoch time).  I know it works because when I render a single series the chart renders correctly.  I think the issue has something to do with the formatting of the overall array. I found this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/89/ that shows the formatting an array with multiple objects.  What's different is that the hash within the array serObj has a key called data: that doesn't have quotes around it. I just can't figure out how to produce the same array result out of rails.

Comment: Hmmmm, there has got to be something else that is different, as the quotes shouldn't matter. Could you show me the entire view source for the chart initialization? You can use http://urldt.com/ to share the code.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience.  Here's the snippet http://urldt.com/252042-453290.

Comment: Ah, there are actual quotes around the array, I see what you are saying. Use "as_json" instead of "to_json" and tell me if that works. I updated my answer to include this.

Comment: as_json produces the following [{"name"=>"AFEXPND", "data"=>"[[-1293840000000, 2.6], [-1262304000000, 2.7],  and instead of the chart heading coming up with invalid date, nothing is rendered.  Within the console the following error is displayed 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ='  I don't think it likes the =>  Here's the entire page http://urldt.com/722155-213569

Comment: closer...still invalid date...Here's the page source http://urldt.com/585741-143469.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25967/discussion-between-matthewkremer-and-johngalt)

Answer (score 0):

use `to_json` so it's more readable

```
series: <%= @serials.to_json %>
```

in your controller, `@serials` is

```
@serials = []
@hack.serials.each do |s|
  s.observations.each do |o|
    @serials << [o.hs_date, o.value]
  end
end
```

Comment: First thanks for responding. When I use your snippet I receive the following error in the console 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &'. Rails is wrapping like  the data like [[&quot;-1293840000000&quot;,&quot;2.6&quot;],.  To combat that I used 'series: <%= raw @serials.to_json %>' however I get the original error of Invalid date. Finally, I need to insert the :name key before each series so I can reference each series.